# Using field types to override meta defaults

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

I was wondering if someone could help me find a solution to this. I didn't see it in the docs. Perhaps I missed it...

I created an entry type with the field type `Meta: Basic`. I would like to use this to override the meta defaults at the entry level. It doesn't appear to do it on it's own and accessing the content via `entry.metaBasic.description` doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the Default meta data with your field type the only addition you need in your code is to pass the `entry.id` to your `craft.sproutSeo.meta` tag:

```
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({ 
    id: entry.id,    
    default: 'default',
    title: entry.title,
    description: entry.body|striptags|slice(0, 160)
}) %}
```

Once you identify the `entry.id` Sprout SEO will handle the rest, prioritizing any values you have in your field types above any values in your Defaults or Code Overrides.

Comment: Ah, so you have to specify the ```entry.id```. That makes sense. Thank you so much.